# python unique identified for each program instance running simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my python programs I often need to distinguish different instances of the same program running simultaneously.

For instance consider an mqtt client subscribing to a topic, if I use the same mqtt client name in each instance of my client, names conflict and the broker is not able to contact them correctly.

A simple global variable can address this, for instance

```
# unique randomized value per program execution that can be used where needed
execution_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
```

this can be used where needed in the code, for instance

```
my_mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(f"my-mqtt-client-{{execution_uuid}}")
```

A naively obvious alternative is using the process id from the underlying operating system, e.g. `os.getpid()` but there are no guarantees that different instances of the same program on different machines have different `PID`. On paper this is very *human friendly* and usable because the same ID can be matched looking at running processes (e.g. `ps` command).

I can think of a more machine-dependent identificators like `CPU ID`+`PID` but on one hand, I am not aware of a portable `CPU ID` and, on the other hand, I don't know if some better alternative is available.

Question is: is there a builtin value/object/constant which can be used to create a unique execution ID, different for every instance of the same program running simultaneously? If no builtins are available for this, is there a consolidated way to obtain an equivalent value?

Comment: This looks like exactly the kind of job a UUID is for. Why not just use a UUID?

Comment: (And why would you truncate the UUID?)

Comment: In the example uuid is truncated for the sake of readability, saying within the mqtt example when you troubleshoot many client ids in your mqtt broker, an 8 character id can be more readable. Three reasons against uuid: theoretically can be less unique than CPU ID, having no intrensic meaning it does not carry any information which can be handy if it cames for free as in CPU ID and PID and third, question is two-folded in case no builtin is available I asked if there is a common way to solve this issue, maybe it is uuid, maybe there is better ones